# CSS file not recognized, path not found in web application

Tags: html, css, jsp, maven

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. The css file is in webapp > resources > css > style.css. It's called in my jsp file correctly as shown below.

I'm running this as a maven build locally with the command tomcat7:run
The page loads up fine but without the css, and if I press f12 to look at the log I see Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). It then shows the file location as http://localhost:8080/CounterWebApp/resources/css/style.css which is ocrrect.

Here are some other code files if they help.

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Counter Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hi</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Maven + Spring MVC Web Project Example</h1>

<h3>Message : ${message}</h3>
<h3>Counter : ${counter}</h3>   
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>CounterWebApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CounterWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Unit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>CounterWebApp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Eclipse project -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <!-- mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- For Tomcat -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/CounterWebApp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you actually try to access http://localhost:8080/CounterWebApp/resources/css/style.css from your browser? It is loading that resource?

Comment: @Ish If you access that link it says 404 the requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** file

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Comment: You may be onto something... I'm not sure yet it's stuck on trying to start the server, it's on info: starting protocol handler but that might just be this old laptop. I'll let you know here in a minute... I hope that works